# Flutter: How to Make Printing Once Every 5 seconds / when user presses a button to leave page?

Tags: flutter, printing, timer

Currently, the value of the elapsed time is printing a gazillion times per second, ok maybe more like 10 times. That's unnecessary. I just want it to print once every 5 seconds or if the user navigates away from the page, print. So that I can record the amount of time spent here.

How do i achieve that?

Attached is my code below:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TimerTest(),
    );
  }
}

class TimerTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerTestState createState() => _TimerTestState();
}

class _TimerTestState extends State<TimerTest> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  int levelClock = 5400;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds:
                levelClock) 
        );

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Countup(
              animation: StepTween(
                begin: 0, // THIS IS A USER ENTERED NUMBER
                end: levelClock,
              ).animate(_controller),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Countup extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countup({Key key, this.animation}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);

    String timerText =
        '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    print('animation.value  ${animation.value} ');

    return Text(
      "$timerText",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 45,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: to record time every 5 seconds, you can use Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5), () => print(time));

Comment: this delays the start of printing value , but after that first 5 seconds, the value is printed continuoulsy again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Timer periodic function for this. For more detail : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

Comment: this delays the start of printing value , but after that first 5 seconds, the value is printed continuoulsy again.

Comment: Do you call timer in build method?